# SonarQube java rule post-initialization

Tags: java, sonarqube, sonar-runner, sonarqube-scan, sonarqube5.1

We use properties (@RuleProperty) in some of our rules and need to do some work on them after those have been initialized. I was wondering whether there is some sort of "post-initialization" concept for Java rules in SonarQube?